# Check pattern of string

Tags: java, regex

I want to ask if i got one variable. 
for example:

```
String i = "1+1+1"
```

how do i check the string contain digit alternate with symbol.
if you have idea how to use regex also can.

my rough idea like this:-

```
Pattern=[0-9\-];
if(i.matches(Pattern) {
system.out.println("true");
else
system.out.println("false);
```

tq. 
still new here

Comment: You want this in java or javascript? You tagged both...

Comment: What have you tried? What results do you expect, what results/errors did you get? What language are you using?

Comment: java.. but javascript also can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use (for integers only))

```
^(\d+[+\/%-])*\d+$
```

Explanation:

`^` start of the string

`\d+[+\/%-]` any integer followed by an operator in the character set

`*` any number of times

`\d+` followed by an integer

`$` end of the string

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV3eT8/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in java then to very a character as an integer at index x use this

```
String s = abc.substring(x, x+1);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
if (scan.hasNextInt())
{
.
}
```

where abc is the given string.
Check weather the first character is integer if so then start from first if not then check second (as it is alternate) then loop over the string verying if integers are present at alternate position.